# scrapy request.priority not works

Tags: python, scrapy

The official documentation explain `scrapy.Request.priority` as follows:

**priority (int)** – the priority of this request (defaults to 0). The priority is used by the scheduler to define the order used to process requests. Requests with a higher priority value will execute earlier. Negative values are allowed in order to indicate relatively low-priority.

But my test is not like that:
`scrapy version: 2.6.2`
`Python version: 3.7.13`

```py
class TestSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'test'

    custom_settings = {
        'DOWNLOAD_DELAY': 5,
        'CONCURRENT_REQUESTS': 1
    }

    def start_requests(self):
        urls = {
            10: 'https://www.baidu.com/s?wd=111111',
            20: 'https://www.baidu.com/s?wd=222222',
            30: 'https://www.baidu.com/s?wd=333333'  # this url may pass to the first request?
        }

        for index, url in urls.items():
            yield scrapy.Request(url,
                                 headers={
                                     'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/103.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'
                                 },
                                 callback=self.parse,
                                 priority=index,  # <- check here!!
                                 meta={'priority': index},
                                 dont_filter=True)

    def parse(self, response, **kwargs):
        self.log(datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%H:%M:%S'))
        self.log(response.request.url)
        title = response.xpath('//title/text()').get()
        self.log(title)
```

following the spider logs, the request order always keeps the same as below:

```
2022-07-26 16:16:10 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.baidu.com/s?wd=111111> (referer: None)
2022-07-26 16:16:10 [test] DEBUG: 16:16:10
2022-07-26 16:16:10 [test] DEBUG: https://www.baidu.com/s?wd=111111
2022-07-26 16:16:10 [test] DEBUG: 111111_百度搜索
2022-07-26 16:16:15 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.baidu.com/s?wd=222222> (referer: None)
2022-07-26 16:16:15 [test] DEBUG: 16:16:15
2022-07-26 16:16:15 [test] DEBUG: https://www.baidu.com/s?wd=222222
2022-07-26 16:16:15 [test] DEBUG: 222222_百度搜索
2022-07-26 16:16:20 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.baidu.com/s?wd=333333> (referer: None)
2022-07-26 16:16:20 [test] DEBUG: 16:16:20
2022-07-26 16:16:20 [test] DEBUG: https://www.baidu.com/s?wd=333333
2022-07-26 16:16:20 [test] DEBUG: 333333_百度搜索
2022-07-26 16:16:20 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
```

Answer (score 0):

When a request is yielded from the `start_requests` method it is immediately handed off to the scrapy engine and then to the scheduler.  If the scheduler doesn't have any previously generated requests in the it's priority queue, then it will be executed immediately upon the next iteration of the reactor event loop.

Upon first initialization of a scrapy spider a new empty scheduler is constructed, and so the first request that is fed to the scheduler for the `start_requests` method will always be the first request executed by the engine. Since the `start_requests` method yields each request one at a time, it is likely that they will be executed in the same order regardless of their priority because the scheduler doesn't know that the later requests with a higher priority exist.

Here is a [link](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/architecture.html#overview) to the scrapy docs overview which describes the step by step process of the scrapy workflow.

---

A solution to your problem would be to sort the urls according to their priority prior to yielding them from the `start_requests` method.

for example:

```
def start_requests(self):
    urls = {10: 'https://www.baidu.com/s?wd=111111',
            20: 'https://www.baidu.com/s?wd=222222',
            30: 'https://www.baidu.com/s?wd=333333'}
    for index, url in sorted(urls.items(), reverse=True):
        yield scrapy.Request(url, callback=self.parse, priority=index, ...)
```